# Intersection of all Holder spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, holder-spaces

Given $0 < \alpha < 1$, consider the Holder space $C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{U})$. Is there any nice subspace of all of these Holder spaces? In other words, whats is
$$
\bigcap_{0 < \alpha < 1} C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{U}) ?
$$
Under some conditions this intersection could be not empty?

Comment: look up log-lipschitz

Comment: Answer depends on your definition of $C^{0,\alpha}$, but if you're assuming functions are bounded (or the domain $U$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$), then you have $C^{0,1}\subset C^{0,\alpha}$ for any $\alpha<1$; so all Lipschitz functions are in that intersection. However, there are functions in all $C^{0,\alpha}$, $\alpha<1$ such that they're nowhere differentiable, so this doesn't characterize the intersection.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know $C^{0,1}(U) \subset C^{0,\alpha}(U)$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $U$ bounded.